# Error installing Laravel

Tags: php, git, laravel-4, localhost, wamp

I am having problems with the installation. I did Composer installation c :/ wamp / www directory for calcined and create a name.

composer create-project laravel/laravel

I have run and I get the following error

Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\fr\laravel\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\fr\laravel\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

I'm using the x64 version of Wamp

Comment: Can you post your composer.json file? And just to make sure, you ran composer install, correct?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the server should correct this for you, but I noticed in your path that the first half uses \ and the last half uses / for the path seperator.

Comment: Wamp server x64 and x86 versions wonder of science that is a problem? Also available in command line error

[RuntimeException]
Failed to clone https://github.com/php-fig/lo
k that it is installed and in your PATH env.

Comment: On windows I would suggest using vagrant http://vagrantup.com and http://puphpet.com to create a virtualbox server on your machine which you can share files with. I can only imagine you will continue having problems using WAMP because of Laravel's heavy reliance on command line.

Comment: I think the way seemed ubuntu :)) I do not solve the problem on windows will start using Linux :))